# Ploting a non-central T distribution with pst-func or tikz?

Tags: pst-func

Does anybody know how to plot a non-central t distribution using `pst-fun` from pstricks or tikz. For the central t, `pst-fun` has the function `psTDist`, but I can find a way to add a $\delta$ ncp to it.

For the central t is quite straigt foward:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-func}    
\begin{document}
    \psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=7.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.25,-0.05)(5.25,0.5)
% Valor de corte z  
\newcommand\z{1.3}
%Dist
\psTDist[nue=9,yunit=1]{\z}{4}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I wonder if I need just to generate the non-central t-distribution and plot the points overlapping.

Thansk!

Comment: Give an example of what you exactly want.

Comment: ... sorry, forgot to post the solution I found... First, generated the non-central t distribution values with R and used the points to do a line graph with ps-plots.

Comment: see answer, a simple use of `\rput`

Comment: Thanks, but you're just plotting two central TDist. I need to plot a non central T distr. In R use `dt(x, df, ncp, log = FALSE)` where `ncp` is the non-centrality parameter.

Comment: Where can I see the formula?

Comment: At wikipedia, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution

Comment: See my edited answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a new version of `pst-func`. Could this be correct? The equations are not really easy ...

(nue -> n for the example)

```
\psset{xunit=1.25cm,yunit=7.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-0.1)(6,0.7)
 \psaxes[Dy=0.1]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,0)(5.5,0.5)
 \psset{linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=100}
 \psNonCentralTDist[linecolor=red,nue=4]{-4}{5}
 \psNonCentralTDist[linecolor=blue,nue=4,lambda=2]{-4}{5}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: That is it!!!!!.... but where can I get the new `pst-func`? (P.S. Are you H. Voß or any other of the package authors? If yes, you guys rock!... if not, you also rock!) THANKS! (and could you also get the non central FDist?)

Comment: will be available tomorrow with a default update of TeXLive/MiKTeX (the preferred way) or install it manually from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func. (version 1.01, also available on all mirrors at tomorrow)   You need `pst-func.tex`  and `pst-func.pro`

Comment: Cool!!! A million thanks! (and please don't forget the non-central F distribution, those are very useful to illustrate test power calculations)

Answer (score 1):

So, this is how I did it... not sure it's the more parsimonious way but...

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-func}    
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{125, 185, 250}
    \psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=7.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4,-0.05)(8,0.5)
% Valor de corte z  
\newcommand\z{1.833}
\def\pdfT#1{\fpeval{1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(#1)^2)}}   
%Dist
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=fillColor!30,linestyle=none]{%
%\psline(-2,0)
\psTDist[nue=9,yunit=1]{\z}{4}
\psline(\z,0)}
%\psTDist[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=fillColor!120,nue=9,yunit=1]{-4}{4}

%NonCentral
\savedata{\mydata}[
-4,4.95603884931306e-07
-3.75,8.27266484115796e-07
-3.5,1.41017659064221e-06
-3.25,2.45724910327064e-06
-3,4.38081829512438e-06
-2.75,7.99628465696469e-06
-2.5,1.49489511813261e-05
-2.25,2.86209005229132e-05
-2,5.60761577907409e-05
-1.75,0.000112246283638675
-1.5,0.000228885682700408
-1.25,0.000473385461861131
-1,0.000986904571583903
-0.75,0.00205706746253531
-0.5,0.00424346475653148
-0.25,0.00856135144220627
0,0.0166768245538877
0.25,0.0309605598258274
0.5,0.0541363810101856
0.75,0.0883066522197213
1,0.133507678070106
1.25,0.186520662362244
1.5,0.240892502696099
1.75,0.288544668758476
1.833,0.3015716
2,0.32229011250974
2.25,0.337962254785326
2.5,0.335200493792012
2.75,0.316828855923198
3,0.287451252549856
3.25,0.252010187554509
3.5,0.214775358753859
3.75,0.178873351874724
4,0.146242775800368
4.25,0.117829676682817
4.5,0.0938663221305527
4.75,0.0741367598730511
5,0.058186348552428
5.25,0.0454670983318004
5.5,0.035427681827488
5.75,0.0275623914314711
6,0.0214327192008265
6.25,0.0166723370299849
6.5,0.0129830403846555
6.75,0.0101265191618662
7,0.00791484135400984
7.25,0.0062012107493628
7.5,0.00487173441525535
7.75,0.00383845547186056
8,0.00303364899963482
]
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray!15,linestyle=none,opacity=0.1]{
\listplot[plotstyle=curve,showpoints=false,linecolor=darkgray,xEnd=1.833]{\mydata}
\psline(\z,0)
}
\listplot[plotstyle=curve,showpoints=false,linecolor=darkgray!85]{\mydata}
\psTDist[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=fillColor!120,nue=9,yunit=1]{-4}{4}

\psline[linewidth=0.75pt,linecolor=gray!75](\z,-0.015)(\z,\pdfT{0.0})
\pcline[linewidth=0.75pt,linecolor=gray!75]{*->}(\z,\pdfT{0.0})(6,\pdfT{0.0})\ncput{\colorbox{white}{\ttfamily Região de Rejeição}}
%Alfa e Beta
\psline[linearc=.90]{*->}(2.1,0.025)(2.25,0.05)(2.5,0.07)\uput[0](2.4,0.07){$\alpha$}
\psline[linearc=.90]{*->}(1.1,0.05)(0.85,0.085)(0.2,0.1)\uput[0](-0.25,0.1){$\beta$}
\uput[0](2,0.175){$1-\beta$}
\psline[linearc=.90]{->}(-1.6,0.3)(-1.3,0.3)(-1.,0.25)
\rput[0](-2.5,0.3){\ttfamily \small \shortstack[c]{Distribuição\\Amostral\\sob $H_0$}}
\psline[linearc=.90]{->}(4.7,0.2)(4.35,0.19)(4,0.16)
\rput[0](5.6,0.2){\ttfamily \small \shortstack[c]{Distribuição\\Amostral\\sob $H_1$}}

%Axes
\psaxes[Dx=1, yAxis=false,xLabels={-4,,-2,,0,,,,4,,6}]{->}(0,0)(-4,0)(8,0.5)
%\psaxes[Dy=0.1,labels=none, ticks=none, xAxis=false,linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(0,0)(-4,0)(4,0.5)
%Labels
\uput[-90](7.75,-.01){$T$} 
%\uput[-150](-0.1,0.5){$f(t)$}
\uput[-90](\z,-0.01){$\, t_{0.95; (9)}$}
\uput[-10](-4.6,0.5){\ttfamily \textbf{Teste Unilateral à Direita}}

\end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the end result:

[image]

The gray line is the non-central t distribution (not exactly simmetric as the blue line  which is the central t distribution).